# What is the purpose for the fallback option in ExtractTextPlugin.extract

Tags: javascript, webpack

Using the example from [webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin):

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          //resolve-url-loader may be chained before sass-loader if necessary
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
    //if you want to pass in options, you can do so:
    //new ExtractTextPlugin({
    //  filename: 'style.css'
    //})
  ]
}
```

What is the purpose of the fallback option?

How I see this snippet to work is:

I instruct webpack to use the `ExtractTextPlugin` on every `.scss` file it encounter. I am telling `ExtractTextPlugin` to use `['css-loader', 'sass-loader']` loaders to generate the css. Webpack will then emit extra `style.css` file containing the css.

I can then reference this file in my index.html or if I am using html-webpack-plugin it will be added automatically to it.

I can remove the `fallback: 'style-loader',` option and everything continues to work.

What does it mean to fallback to `style-loader`?

How/When the fallback gets triggered?

I understand what `style-loader` is doing and how it is modifying the DOM with style tag if I am not using the `ExtractTextPlugin`. I just can't understand the fallback option when I am using `ExtractTextPlugin`.

Comment: This seems to explain what fallback does, not sure if that answers your question though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43403942/448144

Comment: Thank you for the link. I understand all of the reasons raised in the answer. The last paragraph is interesting. `To be clear, the fallback is used after the configured loaders have been applied` but in the case of the above example it will newer gets called because nothing is conditional there. CSS file will be always emitted. As you said it is not answering it fully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have a webpack config with:

```
entry: {
    'pageA': './src/pageA',
    'pageB': './src/pageB',
},
...
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
        },
        ...
    ],
    plugins: [
        ...
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "commons",
            chunks: ["pageA", "pageB"]
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
        ...
    ]
}
```

which let's suppose would get some css into *commons.js* generated by CommonsChunkPlugin above.

When *allChunks* option used by new ExtractTextPlugin() is *false* (default) the output *[name].css* won't contain the css from *commons.js* so some css would remained loaded as javascript with *commons.js* (uuh, ugly). Now the *fallbackLoader* option would say "use the *style-loader*" meaning "add that css into a <style/> when loading *commons.js* in browser".

But you could better use *allChunks* = true for this case, this meaning to force *new ExtractTextPlugin()* to also collect (into the separate css file it creates) the css which otherwise would go into *commons.js*. In this case *fallbackLoader* option would become useless.